# What is the better performance way to hide HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

If I have many following `div`s:

```
<div class="error"> </div>
<div class="error"> </div>
<div class="error"> </div>
<div class="error"> </div>
<div class="error"> </div>
...
```

What is the best way (and best practice) to hide them all at once?

`$('.error').hide()` or

`.addClass('hide')` including `.hide { display: none; }` ?

Comment: Of course to use CSS instead of Javascript. So `display: none;`

Comment: `$('.error').hide()`  in CSS `{ display : none }`

Comment: With CSS `.error{display:none;}` which will hide all elements at once, with js you will still have to wait for page to load to hide them

Comment: With CSS .error{visibility: hidden;}

Comment: There is no BEST way, it is all opinion on that the best is.

Comment: @Arvind yeah but I mean hide them after some behavior (f.e. click somewhere)

Comment: @Arvind: I'm sorry, that's just not correct.

Comment: @epascarello There is a ["better performance way"](http://jsperf.com/best-way-to-hide), though.

Comment: @Blazemonger I know what jsperf is and if you look at my answer I mentioned it. That will show the JS execution speed, it is not going to show redraw/repaints which will be the bigger issue here. This question seems like premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is an opinion, you can run jsperf tests and each browser will be different.

In the end you will either loop in JavaScript and add classes or set style attributes or just rely on the CSS to do the looping for you.

Look at using a selector

```
$(".error").hide();  // or .addClass() or .css("display","none")
```

Under the covers it does:

1. a DOM lookup for one or more elements
2. it is doing a for loop over the set
3. it gets the current element in the loop iteration
4. Applys a css rule in the loop iteration
5. Ends up doing a redraw/repaint

But one way to not have to loop is to just rely on adding a CSS rule higher up in the hierarchy.

CSS:

```
.hideErrors div.error {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document.body).addClass("hideErrors");
```

What this does:

1. DOM lookup for one element
2. Adds one class
3. Ends up doing a redraw/repaint

This way you do not have to loop through and add a class to every element. It would be better to place the "hideError" rule around the element that wraps the error list. So change "body" to that parent element.

Comment: But this is a rather inefficient selector. It still loops over the DOM to find `.error`, and then traverses up for each to look for `.hideErrors`.

Comment: The payoff is to loop the DOM with JavaScript or with CSS.

Comment: You'll have to loop either way. The truth is, it's unlikely that your performance issues will come from where you put your classes. The side effects of having items disappearing off of your document and the reflow/repaint needed for that is what's going to chew up most of the resources.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter which you pick. If it's that important to you, run a benchmark.

Most of the browser's time would be handling layout and repaint anyway, the addition of class or inline style (Because that's what `.hide()` does, add `style="display: none;` to the element) really doesn't matter either way.

If you care about performance, drop jQuery, start using some **[vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)**, learn about **[page performance](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow)** and optimize your JavaScript and CSS selectors.

Honestly, how you modify the DOM is the last thing you should be worrying about :)

Answer (score 0):

The term best isn't really enough information, because it can mean performance (speed) or size (included libraries).

If you already are using JQuery, it is generally a very efficient library and the following is how you would do that after the DOM finished loading.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.error').hide()
});
```

There are other events besides 'DOM ready' that JQuery defines that you can hook the action up to, which is why its a convenient library.

If you are just interested in overall speed and want to avoid external libraries, CSS is generally your fastest way to go, and you would add the class as you stated in your Style Sheet.  This limits when you can hide them to before the DOM loads.

There are best and worst cases for all of the situations you described.  Javascript will have to loop (parse) through the DOM so it will always be slower than pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think add and remove class will be better way to handle this.

In this way you can also do other styling changes related to error message.

```
  css code : 

   .showdiv {
      display : block;
   }

   .hidediv {
      display:none; 
    }

  javascript code :

   $('.error').addClass('showdiv')  

   $('.error').removeClass('hidediv')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you would like them hidden on page load add a class hidden to the divs.

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

To show and hide just use jquery.

```
$('.error').hide();
$('.error').show();
```

Comment: This aint an answer to the question. He asks for the best way.

Comment: Using .hide() and .show() are the current standard and make the most since so it is an answer. Thats what he wanted to know

Comment: *"current standard"* What standard?

Comment: The standard way to do it using jquery